# How does one prove that evaluating an L-term returns the recursive evaluation of all L-terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I was trying to do [exercise 1 on page 30 from some logic notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf). The question was to show:

$$ {t^*}^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = t^{\mathcal A}(\tau_1^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n),\dots,\tau_m^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n))$$

I was trying to do it by induction on length of L-terms. I was having trouble with the base cases. When $|t^*|=1$ then its either a variable or a constant. Lets consider the constant which seems easier. In that case ${t^*}(y_1,\dots,y_n) = t(\tau_1(y_1,\dots,y_n),\dots,\tau_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)) = \underline c$ for some $\underline c \in L^f$. What confuses me is what happens to the above once we bring the interpretation in the given L-structure $A$. What is clear to me is:

$$t(\tau_1(_1,\dots,y_n),\dots,\tau_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)) = \underline c $$

if we interpret $t$ in $\mathcal A $we would get:

$$t^{\mathcal A}(\tau_1(a_1,\dots,a_n),\dots,\tau_m(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \underline c^{\mathcal A} = c$$

whats not specifically clear to me is if I can just bring in the interpretation inside to the tau's also. If I did that it feels like cheating, nearly as if I just asserted what I wanted to prove instead of actually proving it. Or am I allowed to just pretend that I can evaluate $\tau^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_m)$? Like it feels very weird to me to assert:

$$ t^{\mathcal A}(\tau_1^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n),\dots,\tau_m^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) $$

without proof or anything. I thought that exactly what we wanted to prove, that evaluating the top L-term trickled down to the remaining L-terms. What exactly makes:

$$ {t^*}^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = t^{\mathcal A}(\tau_1^{\mathcal A}(y_1,\dots,y_n),\dots,\tau_m^{\mathcal A}(y_1,\dots,y_n)) = \underline c^{\mathcal A}$$

correct?

Intuitively I know that evaluating $t$ gives just out the constant and that we can ignore whatever was fed into the L-term since we are just outputting the constant regardless. Is that why its valid? Because we would have ignored the input not matter what it was and if it was $\tau^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ or any other element of A would have not mattered.

Regardless of the answer, it seems that assuming  $\tau^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ evaluates to something assuming the hypothesis (i.e.  $\tau$ could be any arbitrary L-term, including of the ones in the form of the theorem we are trying to prove. Thus, it might be we need to assume the theorem to be true about composite L-term evaluation for us to assume $\tau^{\mathcal A}$ evaluates to something sensible). So as far as I can tell that should be part of the induction hypothesis (or its only valid to say we have access to tau evaluated on the L-structure by the induction hypothesis, since that could also be of the same for as our hypothesis). So the crux:

$$\tau^{\mathcal A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$

is actually something I can assume I can do without assuming what I am trying to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear about notation, $t(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ is a term, $\tau_i(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ are terms for all $1\leq i\leq m$, and $t^*(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ is the composite term $t(\tau_1(y_1,\dots,y_n),\dots,\tau_m(y_1,\dots,y_n))$.

I'm confused about why you write "assuming $\tau^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ evaluates to something assumes the hypothesis" and "am I allowed to just pretend I can evaluate $\tau^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$?". Given any structure $\mathcal{A}$ and any term $\tau(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, there is a function $\tau^\mathcal{A}\colon A^n\to A$ (this is the first definition on p.29 of your notes). So yes, of course you can evaluate $\tau^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. This is not what the problem is about.

Ok, so as for handling your concern about the base case. Suppose $t(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ is the constant symbol $c$. Then also $t^*(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ is the constant symbol $c$, and the evaluations $t^\mathcal{A}\colon A^m\to A$ and $t^{*\mathcal{A}}\colon A^n\to A$ are both constant functions with value $c^\mathcal{A}$.

So the left-hand side of the equation you're supposed to show is $t^{*\mathcal{A}}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = c^\mathcal{A}$. For the right-hand side, suppose $\tau_i^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = b_i$. Then we have $$t^\mathcal{A}(\tau_1^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n),\dots,\tau_m^\mathcal{A}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = t^\mathcal{A}(b_1,\dots,b_m) = c^\mathcal{A}.$$

You write "Intuitively I know that evaluating $t$ gives just out the constant and that we can ignore whatever was fed into the $L$-term since we are just outputting the constant regardless. Is that why its valid?" Yes!

Comment: my concern is that $\tau(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ might be compositional itself as in the form of the theorem we are trying to prove. So just writing down $\tau^{\mathcal A}(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ might not actually be useful at all unless we know the theorem we are trying to prove is true. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I've clarified my question by adding my above comment to the question. Hope it helps clarify what I mean and my confusion.

Comment: Yes, the $\tau_i$ themselves might be complex terms. That's fine! My answer does not assume anything about the form of the $\tau_i$.

Comment: It seems like you think this exercise is about defining evaluation of terms. It's not - that has already been done in the definition on p. 29. It's about checking that term evaluation and term substitution interact in the way you would expect them to. If you're still confused, maybe you could point to a place in my answer that doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: I guess I don't believe p. 29 is sufficient to convince me of evaluation of terms is valid and thats why we need the exercise I am trying to do.

Comment: Well, your interpretation of the exercise is wrong. The definition on p. 29 is a totally satisfactory defininition of evaluation of terms. And you need to understand and use that definition to solve this exercise.

Comment: Sorry Alex, I don't mean to e annoying. But why am I wrong? I really want to understand why (hence my question). I can't tell the difference between the two, they seem nearly identical to me. If you have any comment I'd greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not annoyed. But you're the one claiming that the p. 29 definition is insufficient. I can't do any more to explain this to you until I understand why you think that.

Comment: I'm not claiming them out of annoyance, I wasn't even aware that my claims were wrong until you pointed it out. My confusion is that this composition of L-terms and evaluating them seems exactly the same as definition on page 29. I can't tell the difference. It seems that in principle we could just unfold the exercise statement with definition on page 29 if we wanted. Or perhaps my confusion is why the exercise is even necessary given definition on page 29. Thanks for your patience and feedback.

Comment: "It seems that in principle we could just unfold the exercise statement with definition on page 29 if we wanted." Exactly! That's all the exercise is asking you to do. The way to formalize "unfolding the statement with the definition" is via a proof by induction on $t$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83880/discussion-between-alex-kruckman-and-pinocchio).